# Arch Linux keeps printing out weird characters in tty

Tags: arch-linux, tty

I cannot login to my Arch Linux machine because the tty keeps getting filled with `^@` characters, and therefore I cannot enter my username or password. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Can you ssh into your machine? If you can, try entering

`sudo dmesg -n 1`

That will block messages from the kernel. Might not help but worth a try

Answer (score 1):

Some protocols use the NUL for keep alives. You could try to set a high keep alive to circumvent this behaviour. E.g. in iTerm2 there is an option called "When idle, sent Ascii code".

> 0 (null, NUL, \0, ^@), originally intended to be an ignored character, but now used by many programming languages to mark the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running:

```
rmmod peaq_wmi
rmmod input_polldev
```