# What is the ^@ key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

What is the key denoted by ^@ when typed in the terminal?

My system is getting spammed by this key, so I have to disable it.

Comment: Your terminal cannot be spammed (only your email account could be spammed). Explain more exactly what is happening. Show the commands you are running, or explain your situation (so **edit your question** to improve it)

Comment: The question is already answered and I've accepted an answer. I'm just clarifying few things with Stephen.

Comment: The real question, not actually asked here, has been asked and answered before: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395494/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412972/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396192/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397436/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402431/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360830/

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, searching didn't get me those questions. Sorry.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch see https://youtu.be/CphNJ4XzxeI

Comment: Questions should be selfcontained, without reference to external videos needed to understand them

Comment: Perhaps your keyboard is mechanically broken (or some physical key is blocked). Clean it

Comment: You understood the question but said it's not possible. Hence the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^@` is not a key, it's the representation of a control character. In that case the NUL character, the one with byte value 0.

If n is the byte value of X, then the byte value of `^X` will be `n ^ 0x40`.

You can tell the byte value of `X` with:

```
printf X | od -An -tu1
```

or (for single byte characters):

```
printf '%d\n' "'X"
```

So here:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "'@"
64
$ echo "$((64 ^ 0x40))"
0
```

For `^?`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "'?"
63
$ echo "$((63 ^ 0x40))"
127
```

(that's the DEL character).

Depending on the terminal, you may be able to enter it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+@</kbd>. On my UK keyboard in xterm on Debian, I get it on <kbd>Ctrl+2</kbd> (shift 2 is `"` on a UK keyboard, but @ on a US keyboard).

The NUL character is ignored by terminals and terminal emulators. It's a *padding* character which in the olden days would have been used by applications to let give the terminal time between two other control characters when there was no flow control.

You'd see that `^@` in a terminal in applications like `vim` that choose it as the visual representation of a NUL. You would also typically see it as the *echo* of a NUL character you enter on input. Either by the terminal driver itself when the terminal line discipline is in `icanon` mode and the `echoctl` parameter is enabled (generally on by default, see `stty -a`), or by line editors in applications (like `readline` used by `bash`).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea as to why my terminal is getting spammed by these characters?

Comment: @BinoyBabu, I've added more information. How exactly is it spamming your terminal? do you see those `^@` as if they had been entered on the keyboard (can you delete them with backspace?) ? Or are they being output by some application? What is running in that terminal when that happens? What's the terminal? A real terminal? A terminal emulator like `xterm`? Please edit your question to add the extra information.

Comment: It blocks me from typing in the keyboard sometimes, and ^@ shows up in the terminal that shows boot progress. No I cannot delete it. It doesn't show up in the terminal app.

Comment: @BinoyBabu, on what hardware? What operating system? Is that after logging in on that _terminal that shows boot progress_? What input device are connected to that machine? Does the problem go away if you unplug some of them?

Comment: Ideapad 320 notebook, Ubuntu 18.04. Not after logging in, this charecter appears to get spammed into the boot progress output. No extra input devices connected.

Answer (score 2):

That is character 0,   ctrl-@.  Eg. Ctrl-A is character 1, Ctrl-M character 13 or newline.